# Firefox addon sdk Request module POST method with payload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to do a POST method inside a firefox add-on to another server, I have been trying to use different ways, and after googling I found out that I should use the Request module from the SDK inside my main.js.

I am using firefox v 23

I tried using the chrome module

```
var xmlhttp = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                        .createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
```

but I got **NS_ERROR_FAILURE**. I even added the permissions in the package.json

```
"permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["https:[some url]"]
  }
```

But it still gives the same error.

I then used the Request module but didn't work so far. I tried a GET method with the Request module and it works fine. But the POST method always returns a **0** status and an empty response.

I tried doing the same request via a browser http client and it worked fine!! But through the code inside the add-on it always returns a 0.

The request sets headers and of course has a payload.

```
var contentObject = {[Valid JSON Object]};

var myRequest = Request({
    url: "https://[some url]",
    headers: {
           "pragma": "no-cache"
    },
    content: contentObject,
    contentType: "application/json", 
    onComplete: function (response) {
        console.log("Status: " + response.status);
        console.log("Response json: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    }).post();
```

Your support is highly appreciated. There are very few resources I found over the internet about this issue and non of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the server script expects a JSON string representation of the contentObject. But this is not how objects are treated by the request module, they are turned to key/value pairs.

So change

```
content: contentObject
```

to

```
content: JSON.stringify(contentObject)
```

Comment: I tried that as well and didn't work. I also tried a GET request and didn't work as well. I am suspecting that it might has to do with the SSL certificate. If you know about any resources about how to set up an SSL certificate using the certificate details in a firefox add-on please let me know

Answer (score 0):

> the POST method always returns a 0 status and an empty response

This might not be direct answer, but I had the same problem last couple of days. A friend who was connected to network via different provider tried the same code and it worked fine. Also, if I remember correctly, I could connect to the port 80 but not to the port where I was sending POST request so that port might be blocked on the network you are connected.